# School Java Escape Room Program

Tags: java

I am writing an escape room project for school which has messages such as a greeting, a win message, a loss message, etc. I stored these messages in a text file and then I read the file and store each line into one ArrayList and to access each line by their respective getter method and I use the `.get` function with their index value. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid hardcoding the index numbers and on top of that is there a way I can just read the file when the program is run instead of having to make an instance of the class and then for example doing `foo.readFile();`

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//package Stage;

public class EscapeRoom{

    ArrayList<String> Messages;
    String fileName;
    private boolean win = false;

    public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        fileName = "test.txt";
        
        File file = new File(fileName); 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            Messages.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();

    }   
    
    public void showGreeting(){
        System.out.println(Messages.get(0));
    }
    public void showDirections(){
        System.out.println(Messages.get(1));
    }
    public void showWin() {
        System.out.println(Messages.get(2));
    }
    public void showLoss() {
        System.out.println(Messages.get(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard coding is fine if you are certain this is the final structure you want to work with. Another option: you can create variable names for the indices, like `private static final int GREETING = 0`, `...DIRECTION = 1`, etc in your class and then use those variable names (`Messages.get(GREETING)` etc).

Comment: Also Java convention is to start your variable names with a small letter. It should be `messages` not `Messages`.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what a properties file is for.  Here is a file I named prompts.properties:

```
greeting = "hello, welcome to my game"
win = "you win, yay"
loss = "sorry bro, you lose"
directions = "escape with your life!"
```

Here is your modified program:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class EscapeRoom {

    Properties prompts = null;

    public void readFile() throws IOException {
        prompts = new Properties();
        prompts.load(new FileInputStream("prompts.properties"));
    }

    public void showGreeting() {
        System.out.println(prompts.get("greeting"));
    }

    public void showDirections() {
        System.out.println(prompts.get("directions"));
    }

    public void showWin() {
        System.out.println(prompts.get("win"));
    }

    public void showLoss() {
        System.out.println(prompts.get("loss"));
    }
}
```

Basically to get a named key-value pair you want something like a map.  Properties are really a special sort of map that understands a file of records that have the format `<key> = <value>`.

Here is the documentation on [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and if you decide to roll your own you would implement the same basic thing with a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: Thank you so much I never knew something like this existed I only took a beginner java class and they never mentioned anything like this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Is there any way for me to learn about more useful content like this? Like a book recommendation or anything?

Comment: I don't have a great answer for you, but instead of leaving you hanging I'll just say that what you asked is hard: Java provides a ton of out-of-the-box functionality and so it's easy for one book, tutorial, class, etc to include an introduction to functionality 'x' that another book might leave out.  That being said I think higher level Java classes or books would all include an introduction to something like Map, Properties.  If you started on one path see if the next course, book, lesson might give you a deeper look into more complicated programming concepts.  Good luck.

Comment: Additionally, could you please accept this answer if you are all set?